# store timepicker value in database

Tags: php, mysql

i want to store the timepicker value in db.when i display it,i got the right time(07 : 39 : PM) but when i store it in db with type TIME it stores like this 00:00:07.
 plz tell me how to store the time in this format (07 : 39 : PM).
  here is my code:
        
        
        
        
        
        
        Time
        
       
        
        
        
        
        
           
            
            
          
        
        
       
       
       
        $('#timepicker1').timepicki();

```
    <?php
    $name1=$_POST["timepicker1"];

    echo "$name1"."<br>";
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   If(!$con)
   {
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db("db1",$con);//db name is db1
  $ins=mysql_query("INSERT into tb values('$name1')");//tb is table name
  $retval=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb"); 
  if(! $retval )
   {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
  echo "Time :{$row['timevalue']} <br> ";      
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you shouldn't use mysql PHP extension since it is deprecated. You should use PDO or mysqli to query your database.

And to avoid SQL-injection vulnerabilities, you should use queries with parameters to sanitize your user input.

Comment: mysql time fields expect values in `hh:mm:ss` format. You're not providing that. `07:39pm` is an unknown/unsupproted format, and mysql is (obviously) not interpreting it properly. You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output is really *07 : 39 : PM*, that would be hard to work on directly. If it is *07:39 PM*, it is easier. You could do something like:

```
$date = new \DateTime('07:39 PM');
$name1 = $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Check your timepicker options to see if you can have a nicer output format.

Comment: Thank u so much @ A.D. I got it. but am getting as 19:39:00. Is it possible to store as 07:39:00 in database.?

Comment: It does not matter how it is stored in the database. 19:39:00 reflects your value. If you want to display later the same date with an other format, use the same syntax I provide you and change the string format in the format method. Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the supported formats.

Comment: hmm...ok ok got it.... Thank u so much @A.D. ur answer is really helpful for me... :) :)